# Bull JS and running different workers on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, service-worker

Looking for advice on how to structure my application when it comes to implementing different workers on a NodeJS, Heroku application.

My Router opens up two end points. One that receives a `GET` request and another that receives a `POST` request with some body content.

```
const Queue = require("bull");

// Create / Connect to a naned worked queue
let workQueue = new Queue("work", client);

router.post("/job/get-data/:id", ensureAuth, async (req, res) => {
  let job = await workQueue.add({
    filename: req.params.id,
    arguments: req.body.data,
  });
  // Does not redirect if the POST request is made using Javascript
  res.json({ id: job.id });
});

router.post("/job/perform-action/:id", ensureAuth, async (req, res) => {
  let job = await workQueue.add({ id: req.params.id, type: req.body.type });
  res.json({ id: job.id });
});
```

Right now, I am using the same Queue for both requests. This is my `worker.js`:

```
const client = require("../config/redis");
let throng = require("throng");
let Queue = require("bull");

let workers = process.env.WEB_CONCURRENCY || 1;
let maxJobsPerWorker = 50;

let workQueue = new Queue("work", client);

function start() {
  workQueue.process(maxJobsPerWorker, __dirname + "/processor.js");
}

throng({ workers, start })
```

And finally this is the processor.js file:

```
const db = require("../config/db");
const scrapperController = require("../controller/scrapperController");
const awsController = require("../controller/awsController");

module.exports = async function (job) {
  // We need to restart the Mongoose process here so it knows what database to search
  db();
  try {
    let scrappedData = null;
    if (job.data.arguments) {
      // With argument, wants to get data
      scrappedData = await scrapperController.getData(
        job.data.filename,
        job.data.arguments
      );

      await awsController.uploadFile(job.data.filename, scrappedData);
      return { value: "Success" };
    } else {
      // With no arguments, whats to perform action
      scrappedData = await scrapperController.performAction(job.data.id);
      return { value: csvFileName };
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject("Unable to scrape data", error);
  }
};
```

Would anyone know how to separate the two end points to different workers? Perhaps one worker would be called 'get info' and another 'do-action'.

My thought was to create different files that would reference different workers and link to different processor files.

Another idea I had was losing the `processor.js` file completely and create sperate worker files that do different things.

I am quite new to workers and how they 'work' so having some difficulty wrapping my mind around them.

Any additional improvements to the above code would be very welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would create different worker queues, so instead of

```
let workQueue = new Queue("work", client);
```

in `app.js` you would have

```
let getInfoQueue = new Queue("getInfo", client);
let doActionQueue = new Queue("doAction", client);
```

then you would call each queue by name

```
let getInfoQueue = new Queue("getInfo", client);
let doActionQueue = new Queue("doAction", client);

function start() {
  getInfoQueue.process(maxJobsPerWorker, __dirname + "/getInfo.js");
  doActionQueue.process(maxJobsPerWorker, __dirname + "/doAction.js");
}
```

Or you could just run the code right there in the `.process()` method